# Put desired color to fill transparent areas of an image in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on implementing a loader animation on my website, and I've noticed that there's a transparent background on my image. Is there a way to override this transparent background using CSS? It seems that setting a background color is not having any effect in covering up the transparency.

For instance, consider the image of a Pokeball below, which has a transparent background.

[image]

Below is my sample code on how I animate my loader.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  .loader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #f7f9fb;
    transform: opacity 0.75s, visiblity 0.75s;

    img {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      animation: loading 2s ease infinite;
    }

    @keyframes loading {
      from {
        transform: rotate(0turn);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
      }
    }
  }

  .loader-hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <title>Loader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 
    <div class="loader">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/NFzNjN86/pokemon-ball.png" alt="pokeball" />
    </div>
    <script src="/app/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your image does not have a transparent background.

Comment: Given image in the example does not have transparent background. Frist verify that your image have transparent background. Then it's possible to give a desired colour to the background with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that the original image is not saved correctly as png. When you see the chessboard pattern it's likely that you have downloaded it wrongly. Try to import the image in something like Figma and see if it actually has a transparent background.

Comment: It's true that the given image have no transparent background. But it's not necessarily a wrongly downloaded. Because people create images with transparent background, on purpose (by design).

Comment: Yeah it make sense now. Shame on me xD. Thank you for the help guys, appreciate it...